# If you never save a Prompto photo, what happens at the end?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

Just before the end boss, Noctis wants to select a photo from Prompto, to take with him.

So you have, as choices, all photos that you made Prompto save during the trip.

But, if you never saved a photo, or deleted all saved photos before that point, what are your choices?

EDIT: I don't know how my question is not clear. I'm not asking what do photos do, but what happens in the big moment at the end where you have to choose one of your saved photos. If there are no choices, what happens? Does it just skip that part of the cutscene, is it prefilled with photos that Prompto will say 'oh, we dont have any, lucky us I got a secret stash!'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't get through the game with no pictures saved, as two are saved automatically.

From multiple users in [this thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/FFXV/comments/5jfodi/end_spoilers_what_happens_when_you_dont_save_the/), it appears that you will always have the group picture from the beginning and the picture taken before the group departs for Altissia.

> there are always 2 choices (one with the 4 guys, and another from just before you depart for artissia on the boat with cid and the cape caem guys)

---

> There are some Prompto photos that are standard for everyone at key story events. It's likely that in the event you have none saved, it'll load these for you to look through and choose. I don't think they'd spend time with animating that section or the end credits if it was going to be completely blank.

---

> I saved zero pictures and @imitebmike Is correct; there are two default photos that are automatically saved (the two he mentions)

Comment: Just to clarify, these will appear even if you delete them?

Comment: Dont remember that theres a way to go in Promptos camera and delete them.

Comment: @Allball103 make a separate question.